# Display selected option on same page after reload page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a select option when i select any items after that i click on button page reload on same page. i want to to get this selected option after reload page also.
Here is PHP Script

```
<select id="poet_id" class="filter-btn txtEntry2">
<option value="">-Poet- </option>
<?php foreach ($poet_list as $poet){ ?>
    <option selected="selected" value="<?php  echo $poet["PI"]; ?>"><?php if($poet["PE"]){ echo $poet["PE"]; } elseif($poet["PH"]){ echo $poet["PH"]; }else{ echo $poet["PU"];} ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Here is my jquery script

```
$(function() {
  $("#video_search").click(function() {
    var poet_id = $("#poet_id").val(); //alert(poet_id);    
    var singer_id = $("#singer_id").val(); //alert(singer_id);

    if (singer_id == "" && poet_id == "") {
      //alert('Please Select Singer name');
      $("#response").html("Please Select Singer Or Poet Name").show().fadeOut(3000).css("color", "red");
    } else {
      //var info='type='+ type_id +'&category=' + category;
      var info = 'singer_id=' + singer_id; {
        if (info) {
          //alert(info);
          window.location.href = "videos.php?singer_id=" + singer_id + '&poet=' + poet_id;
        } else {
          alert('No Data Found');
        }

      }
    }
  });
});
```

I am using this script but i am failed to display selected option on another page.
Thanks

Comment: @StefanoZanini has nothing to do with javascript variables being stateless... OP is using GET query string to pass the data

Comment: @charlietfl noted, sorry, I retracted the flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting selected on all options. Make it conditional to value of `$poet["PI"]` matching value of `$_GET['poet']`.

Something like:

```
<?php 
$poetId = isset($_GET['poet']) ? $_GET['poet'] : false;
foreach ($poet_list as $poet){ 
  $selected = '';
  if($poetId && $poetId === $poet["PI"]){
      $selected = 'selected="selected";
  }

?>
    <option <?php echo $selected;?> value="<?php  echo $poet["PI"]; ?>"><?php if($poet["PE"]){ echo $poet["PE"]; } elseif($poet["PH"]){ echo $poet["PH"]; }else{ echo $poet["PU"];} ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: charlietfl Thanks a lot brother. you saved my time

Comment: can you please explain this line $poetId = isset($_GET['poet']) ? $_GET['poet'] : false;

Comment: it's called a ternary conditional .... shorthand `if()` ... `if(isset($_GET['poet']) { $poetId = $_GET['poet']; } else {  $poetId = = false}`